# Read csv with two headers into a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, spreadsheet

Apologies for the seemingly simple question, but I can't seem to find a solution to the following re-arrangement problem.

I'm used to using `read.csv` to read in files with a header row, but I have an excel spreadsheet with two 'header' rows - cell identifier (a, b, c ... g) and three sets of measurements (x, y and z; 1000s each) for each cell:

```
a           b       
x    y  z   x   y   z
10   1  5   22  1   6
12   2  6   21  3   5
12   2  7   11  3   7
13   1  4   33  2   8
12   2  5   44  1   9
```

csv file below:

```
a,,,b,,
x,y,z,x,y,z
10,1,5,22,1,6
12,2,6,21,3,5
12,2,7,11,3,7
13,1,4,33,2,8
12,2,5,44,1,9
```

How can I get to a data.frame in R as shown below?

```
cell x  y   z
a    10 1   5
a    12 2   6
a    12 2   7
a    13 1   4
a    12 2   5
b    22 1   6
b    21 3   5
b    11 3   7
b    33 2   8
b    44 1   9
```

Comment: You will find that you get better answers if you take the time to make your question reproducible. Please follow the guidelines (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), paying special attention to the part about `dput()`. Thanks!

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, `dput()` is nice and I generally appreciate it, but how would you go about using `dput()` for a `read.csv()` problem? Hosting the CSV on Dropbox might be an alternative, but questions of permanence arise. I think *this* question--even without the edit by the OP--is reasonable, though a *little* bit more work for the rest of us.

Comment: @mrdwab I was thinking he could `dput(read.csv())`, since this isn't necessarily a read.csv problem but a reshaping post-read-in.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, actually, I didn't even know you can use `dput()` that way. Interesting to know! Thanks! Still, my "reading" was different, though. I guess I saw it more as a problem of *first* working with files with multiple column headers, and *second*, reshaping the data. I came to that conclusion from the second para, where the OP said they are used to using `read.csv()` but were somewhat stuck at the two header rows issue.

Comment: @mrdwab `read.csv()` returns a `data.frame` so you can `dput()` it.  Ain't R grand!  But point taken, and I enjoyed your explication.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, thanks for the comment. Like @mrdwab it wasn't initially clear to me that this was a case for `dput{)`, that's why I added the `csv` contents, but the comments here are useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use base R `reshape()`:

```
temp = read.delim(text="a,,,b,,
x,y,z,x,y,z
10,1,5,22,1,6
12,2,6,21,3,5
12,2,7,11,3,7
13,1,4,33,2,8
12,2,5,44,1,9", header=TRUE, skip=1, sep=",")
names(temp)[1:3] = paste0(names(temp[1:3]), ".0")
OUT = reshape(temp, direction="long", ids=rownames(temp), varying=1:ncol(temp))
OUT
#     time  x y z id
# 1.0    0 10 1 5  1
# 2.0    0 12 2 6  2
# 3.0    0 12 2 7  3
# 4.0    0 13 1 4  4
# 5.0    0 12 2 5  5
# 1.1    1 22 1 6  1
# 2.1    1 21 3 5  2
# 3.1    1 11 3 7  3
# 4.1    1 33 2 8  4
# 5.1    1 44 1 9  5
```

Basically, you should just skip the first row, where there are the letters a-g every third column. Since the sub-column names are all the same, R will automatically append a grouping number after all of the columns after the third column; so we need to add a grouping number to the first three columns.

You can either then create an "id" variable, or, as I've done here, just use the row names for the IDs.

You can change the "time" variable to your "cell" variable as follows:

```
# Change the following to the number of levels you actually have
OUT$cell = factor(OUT$time, labels=letters[1:2])
```

Then, drop the "time" column:

```
OUT$time = NULL
```

## Update

To answer a question in the comments below, if the first label was something other than a letter, this should still pose no problem. The sequence I would take would be as follows:

```
temp = read.csv("path/to/file.csv", skip=1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
GROUPS = read.csv("path/to/file.csv", header=FALSE, 
                  nrows=1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
GROUPS = GROUPS[!is.na(GROUPS)]
names(temp)[1:3] = paste0(names(temp[1:3]), ".0")
OUT = reshape(temp, direction="long", ids=rownames(temp), varying=1:ncol(temp))
OUT$cell = factor(temp$time, labels=GROUPS)
OUT$time = NULL
```

Comment: What if the OP has another first label other than a trivial letter? Would it be possible to read only the first line?

Comment: @lselzer, I've added an update. I don't think it's difficult--you just need to create an object that reads in just the first line and uses that for the "`cell`" labels.

Comment: @mrdwab thanks for the answer. It worked fine for me. I'm sort of glad it wasn't something entirely trivial.

Comment: @mrdwab, while the first approach worked, for an extended file with lablels other than letters the penultimate line of your update fails with: `> OUT$cell = factor(temp$time, labels=GROUPS)
Error in factor(temp$time, labels = GROUPS) : 
  invalid labels; length 9 should be 1 or 0`

Comment: @user441706, difficult to say without seeing the actual data. You might need to add `levels` to your `factor()` statement too. Double-check your `GROUPS` to make sure that it is the same length as the number of factor levels. (In your simplified example, the number of groups would be 2 (`a` and `b`), as are the number of factor levels.)

Comment: @mrdwab, Thanks, I changed your `OUT$cell = factor(temp$time, labels=GROUPS)` to `OUT$cell = factor(OUT$time, labels=GROUPS)` and preceeded it with `levels(OUT$time) <- length(GROUPS)` –  that seemed to work.